# VSTS ExternalTfsBuild file access

Tags: build, azure-devops, release

I have a build provided by a third party via the ExternalTfsBuild service endpoint in VSTS (Type: Team Foundation Server/Team Services). 
I can use the build successfully in a Release pipeline and deploy it to Azure but I also want to extract some script files from it.

Ideally I'd like to store the files back into VSTS Git so I can track their changes over time. Anyone done this before?

Comment: Do you mean that you get the build artifacts from other TFS/VSTS and want to extract the artifacts and store the files into your VSTS repository?

Comment: hi @AndyLi-MSFT, yes, I don't want their source code, I want their build artefacts.

Comment: Then you can download the build artifacts and copy the needed files to a staging folder, then run the Git commands to push the files to VSTS Git as I mentiond in below answer. You can use the extensiont [TFS artifacts for Release Management](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vss-services-externaltfs) to download the external build artifacts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, seems the real requirement is syncing between the external TFS and your VSTS Git.

If it is, then you can reference below articles to do that:

- [Synchronizing TFS 2015 and VSTS with GitHub](https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/leonj/2017/01/24/synchronizing-tfs-2015-and-vsts-with-github/#GITHUB_TFS)
- [Keep Git repository in sync between VSTS / TFS and Git](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/10/22/keep-git-repository-in-sync-between-vsts-tfs-and-git/)

However if you just want to extract some script files and commit/push them to VSTS Git, then you can directly extract and copy them to a staging folder, then use the Git command to push back to VSTS Git, you can reference **Sync from GitHub to VSTS** part in [this article](https://blogs.microsoft.co.il/leonj/2017/01/24/synchronizing-tfs-2015-and-vsts-with-github/#GITHUB_TFS).